# Another question on reciprocals of partial derivatives

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Consider the function $f(\mathbf{x},g(\mathbf{x}))$, where $f:\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$, $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $g:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$.

I want to take the gradient $\nabla_{\mathbf{x}}f(\mathbf{x},g(\mathbf{x}))$, which I think should give me this...

$$
\nabla_{\mathbf{x}}f(\mathbf{x},g(\mathbf{x})) = \left[\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial g}\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_1},\cdots,\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial g}\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_n}\right]^{T}
$$

Finding the derivatives $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_i}$ is a little tricky.  Naively I thought I could do something like

$$
\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_i} = \frac{\partial g}{\partial f}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}
$$
under the assumption that $\frac{\partial g}{\partial f} = \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial g}\right)^{-1}$, yet substituting such an expression into the equation for the gradient would give me the following form
$$
\nabla_{\mathbf{x}}f(\mathbf{x},g(\mathbf{x})) = \left[\cdots,2\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i},\cdots\right]
$$

Clearly the reciprocal argument used to find $\frac{\partial g}{\partial f}$ has been abused here, but I'm not clear why.  I was under the impression that such an argument could be used as long as the same variables are being held constant, and I think I am doing that.  I guess the remaining weak spot is that I have fundamentally misunderstood the application if inverse function theorem in this context?

Comment: your domain for $f$ makes no sense as written

Comment: $f$ should be defined on $\mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R^n$. Not on $\mathbb R^n$. $h(x)= f(x,g(x))$ is defined in $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: Yes, sorry, corrected.

Comment: I would suggest that you define $h(x)=f(x,g(x))$. That will help for your derivations... and to use the chain rule properly.

Comment: I'm grateful for the hint, but unclear how to proceed - had I known how to use the chain rule properly I presumably wouldn't be in this mess now.  Would you be able to expand in an answer that I can then accept?

Comment: See the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $h(x) = f(x,g(x))$ and let suppose that both $f,g$ are continuously differentiable. $h$ is defined on $\mathbb R^n$ and takes values in $\mathbb R$.
We can write

$$h(x) = (f \circ k)(x)$$ where $k(x) = (x, g(x))$ is a map from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R^n$. The [Fréchet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative) or [total](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative) derivative of $k$ at $x$ is given by

$$k^\prime(x)(r) = (r, g^\prime(x)(r)).$$ For $x \in \mathbb R^n$ given, $k^\prime(x)$ is a linear map from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R^n$. Knowing that the derivative of $f$ at $(x_1,x_2)$ is

$$f^\prime(x_1,x_2)(r,s) = \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(x_1,x_2)\right)(r) + \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}(x_1,x_2)\right)(s) $$ we get applying the chain rule:

$$\begin{aligned}h^\prime(x)(r) &= \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(x,g(x))\right)(r) + \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}(x,g(x))\right)(g^\prime(x)(r)\\
&=\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(x,g(x)) + \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}(x,g(x)) \circ g^\prime(x)\right)\right)(r)
\end{aligned} $$ For $x \in \mathbb R^n$ given, $h^\prime(x)$ is a linear map from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R$. In term of gradient notation we would get:
$$\nabla h(x) = (\partial_1 f(x,g(x)))^T+ (Dg(x))^T(\partial_2 f(x,g(x)))^T$$ where $Dg(x)$ is the [Jacobian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) of $g$ at $x$.

*Note 1: as always with multivariate functions and derivatives, it is critical to understand to which spaces belong all the written maps.*

*Note 2: on my side, I much prefer total derivative or Fréchet derivative notations that are more general than gradient, Jacobian, and so on. But that's a question of test!*

Comment: Thank you for this.  I'm finding the notation a little hard to follow, but I think the second inline equation should read $k'(x)(h) = (h,g'(x)(h))$?  So that I understand - what you're writing down there is the product of the derivative of $k$ and $h(x)$?

Comment: Thanks for noticing the typo that is now fixed! $g^\prime(x)(h)$ means: the derivative of $g$ at $x$ applied to vector $h$. Remember that $g^\prime(x)$ is a linear map from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R^n$ in the case of $g$. $k^\prime(x)$ is a linear map from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R^n$.

Comment: I've spent the last couple of days trying to understand what you write but I am still cluelues. I don't understand what we mean to apply the gradient of $f$ to the tuple $(h,k)$, or whats happening when we apply the gradient of $h$ at $x$ to $h$ itself, when the final result you use at the end is just based of the gradient of $h$.  I don't understand the use of the compositionality operator in the penultimate line?  I thought the use should be $(f\circ g)(x)$.  Would you be able to provide some intuition for the answer?  Or  use the notation in my question that I am familiar with?

Comment: In all what I wrote, for any map $a$, $a^\prime$ is the [Fréchet derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative?wprov=sfti1). I suggest that you look at the Wikipedia entry to understand my notations. And at the gradient entry to understand that link between both.

Comment: Ah, I have never heard of the Frechet derivative before - thank you for introducing the concept, and I shall read and try and understand!

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't understand - I fear this question was too general, so with your approval I will accept the answer, as I am sure it is correct, and ask a new question.  My key failure now is that, if $f:\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$, as discussed in comments to the original question, and then $h(x) = f(x,g(x))$, then how is $h$ anything other than a scalar?.  In the derivation, it seems we are treating is as a vector.  I am also still confused about the second term in the final expression, but the dimensionality of $h$ is my biggest issue

Comment: @Pablo No, I made a mistake... Reading incorrectly that $f : \mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$. I'll update my answer to take into consideration that $f : \mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$. The beauty of Fréchet is that almost nothing will be changed in therm of notations, just the spaces of the objects will change.

Comment: @Pablo New release of my answer delivered!

Comment: using $h$ for both the function name and also the "displacement vector" is probably not a good idea

Comment: @peek-a-boo You're right! This is even a very bad idea. That I'm going to fix now.

Comment: Okay, this all makes a lot more sense now, thank you!